# How to set the return type of the following c++ code with enable_if

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I copied the following piece of code from one of the members in Stackoverflow. It works well. Thanks guys!

However, I could not figure out where is the return value defined. Can anyone explain to me what's the return value's type?

What if I want to change the return value type to be void (no return value)?

also, what is the point to have typename Dummy in this piece of code? why there is a '...' ?

Can anyone give an explanation? Thanks!

```
template<typename Traits>
class Robot {

public:
    template<typename... Dummy, typename U = Traits>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ResearchTraits, U>::value>::type
    MyFunction() {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Dummy) == 0, "Do not specify template arguments!");
        std::cout << "research based." << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename... Dummy, typename U = Traits>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ProductionTraits, U>::value>::type
    MyFunction() {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Dummy) == 0, "Do not specify template arguments!");
        std::cout << "production based." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), you see `enable_if` has two template parameters, the second defaulting to `void`:

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
```

In your case, `B` is equal to `std::is_base_of<ResearchTraits, U>::value`, and `T` is omitted, therefore defaults to `void`

From the same page:

> If B is true, std::enable_if has a public member typedef type, equal
>   to T; otherwise, there is no member typedef.

Your return type is `std::enable_if<...>::type`, which is thus equal to `T`, which in your case is `void`.

Comment: is this the normal practice to 'select' which member function to be used ?  or there is a dedicated syntax specifically for such selection? MyFunction's return type is always void, so I don't really need to select anything?

Comment: Looks like this is a way of specifying different function overloads depending on whether the template parameter of `Robot` is derived from `ProductionTraits` or `ResearchTraits`. I'm not totally sure if it's also doing something else, so I'll leave that question to someone a little more knowledgable about this

Comment: The `Dummy` variable prevents a user from calling that function with custom template parameters, forcing `U` to always default to `Traits`. I can't think of why this would be necessary though, instead of just plugging `Traits` directly into the `is_base_of`